# How to compare text before given character

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am working with output of a program that look like this:

```
Computer1@domain.com:randomtext1:completion of randomtext
Computer2@domain.com:randomtext4:completion of randomtext
Computer1@domain.com:randomtext3:completion of randomtext
Computer3@domain.com:randomtext2:completion of randomtext
Computer2@domain.com:randomtext5:completion of randomtext
Computer1@domain.com:randomtext6:completion of randomtext
Computer3@domain.com:randomtext7:completion of randomtext
Computer2@domain.com:randomtext8:completion of randomtext
```

So as you can see, the same computer will give me more than one result, but each result is different in terms of content and length (but all in one line). Some computers will give only 1 result and some will give up to 15 results, depending on the activity of that computer.

What I want is that I would like to see only one result of each computer instead of all results. What I do right now is that I sort it and delete the replica's manually which is not very helpful! I tried to use commands such as **diff** and **comm** but no luck (which makes sense since the lines are very different).

So, how can I change the output using via terminal to be similar to this one:

```
Computer1@domain.com:randomtext1:completion of randomtext
Computer2@domain.com:randomtext4:completion of randomtext
Computer3@domain.com:randomtext2:completion of randomtext
```

The idea in my head is that maybe there is a way to tell the terminal "Compare whatever before the .com or before the first : and delete replica's"

Comment: Which result? First? Last? Any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If any result would do, use `sort` and ask for unique output:

```
sort -ut: -k1,1 foo
```

The options:

- `-k 1,1` only use the first field for sorting
- `-t:` use `:` as the field separator
- `-u` remove duplicates from the output based on the sort field

Similarly, in awk:

```
awk -F: '!a[$1]++' foo
```

In both commands, using `:` as the field separator, we're only looking at the first field.

This `awk` command (and, I think, the `sort` command as well) will print only the first result.

To get the last result:

```
awk -F: '{a[$1] = $0} END {for (i in a) print a[i]}'
```

Here, we use the first field as an index into the array `a`, and save the whole line into the array. Each time a duplicate result is encountered, it overwrites the previous entry. And, at the end, just print all lines in the array, which will now have only the last results of each system.

Comment: Thank you very much! The first option worked! Could you please add explanation for it? So future readers can know the meaning of it? For me any result will work, but I am curious to see how would you pick up the last/first results? Could you please also show that?
Thanks again!